# Having troubles with a conditional count in SQL

Tags: sql, database, count

I'm working on an SQL project (involving a library database) and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make a conditional count.

So, I have 4 tables: Imprumuturi, Cititori, Autori, Carti. I need to list the 'Cititori' that have more than one borrowed 'Carti' at the current time.

I tried to use

```
SELECT cititori.nume_cititor,COUNT(imprumuturi.pk_cititor) 
AS numar_imprumuturi FROM cititori, imprumuturi 
WHERE imprumuturi.data_return IS NULL GROUP BY cititori.nume_cititor
HAVING COUNT(imprumuturi.pk_cititor)>1 
ORDER BY cititori.nume_cititor;
```

And while it lists all the 'Cititori", it doesn't count the number of active borrowed 'Carti' as it should.

Can I get a hint or some help on how to make it work?

[These are the fields of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUom9.png)

Comment: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You should probably write your query in English if you want to get an answer. How should anyone who doesn't speak Romanian know what "readers" you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you missed the relation between the tables:

```
SELECT cititori.nume_cititor,COUNT(imprumuturi.pk_cititor) 
AS numar_imprumuturi 
FROM cititori
INNER JOIN imprumuturi ON imprumuturi.pk_cititori = cititori.pk_cititori
WHERE imprumuturi.data_return IS NULL 
GROUP BY cititori.nume_cititor
HAVING COUNT(imprumuturi.pk_cititor)>1 
ORDER BY cititori.nume_cititor;
```

As suggested, you should not use the old implicit join syntax based on comma-separated table names and where condition, but use explicit join syntax.

Comment: Thank you a lot. One question thought: why shouldn't I use old implicit join sintax?

Comment: because is  old  ..  is not clear , is not clear which relation is establishid between the involved  table  ..  (the implicit join sintax is old far 1992 ..  i think 30 year is a lot for a correct and common sql syntax) ..and last don't let you manage properly the outer join  (left join )

Comment: @RobertPloscaru The join syntax separates the link criteria (ON) from the search criteria (WHERE). It's easier to read, and it's easier to avoid unintended cross joins by forgetting a link criteria.

Comment: Btw, in the question it is mentioned that `more than one borrowed 'Carti'` But this query doesn't even use pk_carte. Is this really returning what's expected?